Wi-Fi keeps disconnecting and I have an Additional Driver warning in the Software & Updates interface
I've been using a Lenovo E16 running Ubuntu 24.4 LTS for the past six months without issues. Yesterday, I connected external speakers via a 3.5mm jack (not Bluetooth). After a few hours of normal operation, my Wi-Fi suddenly disconnected, and the Wi-Fi settings completely disappeared from the network options. I tried resetting the network manager, but it didn’t resolve the issue. I had to restart the machine to regain Wi-Fi connectivity. However, now the Wi-Fi disconnects every three hours or so, with the settings disappearing again.
Check the commands regarding the information of my Wi-Fi/network:
$ lspci | grep -i network
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: fc:5c:ee:59:bf:62
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:50 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fd604000-fd604fff memory:fd600000-fd603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: b8:1e:a4:84:15:db
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.68.69 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:79 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd500000-fd5fffff

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"GEXP Software"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: 02:EB:B6:C5:EF:ED
          Bit Rate=1.0806 Gb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-30 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:302   Missed beacon:0

gpd0      no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

br-abf24a185f6c  no wireless extensions.

veth1e8da7f  no wireless extensions.

$ lspci -k | grep -A 3 -i network
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller
    Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
    Kernel modules: rtw89_8852be
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. NV2 NVMe SSD SM2267XT (DRAM-less) (rev 03)

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ sudo ethtool -i wlan0
Cannot get driver information: No such device

I was reviewing the Software & Updates app and noticed an issue, as shown in the screenshot. Are you familiar with this problem?

